# what is the difference between Go get and Go download commands

Tags: go

could you explain what the following commands on go doing exactly

```
 go get golang.org/dl/go.1.15.6
 go1.15.6 download
```

when using go get what exactly happens on the background is it only downloading the go.1.15.6 and what go1.15.6 download doing exactly ?

Answer (score 4):

The command `go get golang.org/dl/go.1.15.6` is deprecated.  Use `go install golang.org/dl/go.1.15.6` instead.

The command `go install golang.org/dl/go.1.15.6` downloads, builds and installs a program named `go.1.15.6`. This program does not include the Go installation. Read the  [go install](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) documentation for more details.

The command `go1.15.6 download` runs the program installed in the previous step with the `download` argument. When run this way, the program downloads the associated version of Go. After downloading, the [Go tool sub-commands](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go) for that version can be invoked using the `go1.15.6` program. Read [Managing Go installations](https://go.dev/doc/manage-install) for more details on the `go1.xx.x` command.

Note that there is not a `go download` sub-command.  Download is a feature in the `go1.xx.x` commands.